# Merging [openui5] and [sapui5]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

The difference of [sapui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sapui5) and [openui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openui5) is described in [this developer guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sapui5).

On Stack Overflow, I never know which tag to use, since:

> 'sapui5' covers both the Dec 2013 Open Sourced version of the toolkit commonly known as "OpenUI5" and also the original licensed version "SAPUI5".

For me it only makes sense to migrate the `openui5` tag to `sapui5`.