# Merging the tags [ui5], [sapui], [openui5] and [sapui5]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Related: [Merging [openui5] and [sapui5]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324113/merging-openui5-and-sapui5). Proposal: the tags [ui5], [sapui], [openui5] and [sapui5] should be merged. the desciption of the tag [sapui5] already says, that it covers both SAPUI5 and OpenUI5. preferably should the three tags merged to the tag [sapui5] because this one has already the most subscribers and tagged questions. currently there are slipping many questions through which are either only tagged with the tag [openui5] and/or the tag [ui5] and/or the tag[sapui] but not with the tag [sapui5]. especially new users a confused which tag is to use.

Comment: The concern here, before we do a merge, would be whether the tags are currently being used correctly. If we merge them first, it makes cleanup much more difficult. If we could have someone who is knowledgeable about this subject (is that you?) look through the questions currently with these tags and see if they're all used identically and ready for a merge, that would be very helpful.

Comment: there are 1180 [openui5] and 93 [ui5] questions. will take me a while but i check each one if it could be tagged with [sapui5] considering [sapui5] covering both SAPUI5 and OpenUI5. if i find a question that could be tagged with [sapui5] should i edit the tags? and if i shouldn't edit them, how should i treat questions that can't be tagged with [sapui5]?

Comment: Since you don't have full editing privileges, you probably shouldn't try and submit edits that change *just* the tags. If you want to submit edits that change tags *and* clean up other problems with the post, please feel free to do so, and you'll get +2 points for your trouble (for each approved edit). But the community will very likely frown on edits that just change tags, so you can also just post links to the questions that need to have tags removed here (edit the question, or post an answer), and I or someone else with full editing privileges can do that.

Comment: Most of the time, I can do this for subjects I'm familiar with just by scrolling through the page of questions, not even having to navigate to each one of them. Occasionally you have to click on one and read it more carefully. One trick that can narrow down the questions you have to look through is tag exclusion searches. Use the `-` operator in front of a tag to exclude posts that have that tag. So you can do `[c] -[c++]` for example to find all questions with the [c] tag that do *not* also have the [c++] tag.

Comment: alright, thank you. going to start tomorrow.

Comment: checked [ui5]. ready for a merge with [sapui5].

Comment: checked [sapui]. ready for a merge with [sapui5].

Comment: checked [openui5]. ready for a merge with [sapui5].

Comment: to sum up: [ui5], [sapui] and [openui5] can be merged with [sapui5] without a mess-up. makes sense because openui5 is the open source clone of sapui5 minus some fancy libraries. therefore encloses sapui5 openui5. my concerns are: is [sapui5] to be found for someone who wants to post or search a question regarding openui5 and doesn't know that this is covered by [sapui5]? what if someone creates a new [ui5], [sapui] or [openui5]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for letting this linger so long after your reply. I had left it open in a tab, but on a different machine than the one I've been using recently. Heh.

Anyway, the requested merges have now been done, and synonym mappings created:

- [sapui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sapui5) ← [ui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui5)
- [sapui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sapui5) ← [sapui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sapui)
- [sapui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sapui5) ← [openui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openui5)

I ensured that, even though time had passed since you looked through these, no new questions had been created with those tags that *didn't* use [sapui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sapui5), so I could be pretty confident that the merge was reasonable.

> my concerns are: is [sapui5] to be found for someone who wants to post or search a question regarding openui5 and doesn't know that this is covered by [sapui5]? what if someone creates a new [ui5], [sapui] or [openui5]?

This won't be a problem, because synonym mappings have been created. If someone tries to use (or search for) either [ui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui5), [sapui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sapui), or [openui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openui5), the tag will automatically redirect to [sapui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sapui5). Magic. :-)

You'll see this if you try it. Well, you should. It might not work immediately; blame caching, as ever.